Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' angular 17
I am using Angular version 17 cli
<div class="row" [class.dark-category-box]="themeService.isDark()" *ngIf="trendingCategories">

I get this error:
 Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' (used in the 
'CategoriesStyleThreeComponent' component template).
If the 'ngIf' is an Angular control flow directive, please make sure that either the 
'NgIf' directive or the 'CommonModule' is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.

This is the app.module:
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgxScrollTopModule } from 'ngx-scrolltop';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import {CategoriesStyleThreeComponent} from './components/common/categories-style-three/categories-style-three.component'

 @NgModule({
 declarations: [],
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxScrollTopModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [],
     exports: [CategoriesStyleThreeComponent]
 })
   export class AppModule { }

and my component code:
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { ThemeCustomizerService } from '../theme-customizer/theme-customizer.service';
 import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
 import { CategoryService } from '../../../services/category.service';
 import { Category } from '../../../models/category.model';


@Component({
selector: 'app-categories-style-three',
standalone: true,
imports: [RouterLink],
templateUrl: './categories-style-three.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./categories-style-three.component.scss']
})
export class CategoriesStyleThreeComponent implements OnInit {
trendingCategories: Category[];
numCategories: number = 5;

isToggled = false;

constructor(public themeService: ThemeCustomizerService,
    private categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.themeService.isToggled$.subscribe(isToggled => {
        this.isToggled = isToggled;
    });
}

toggleTheme() {
    this.themeService.toggleTheme();
}

ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.loadTrendingCategories();
}

loadTrendingCategories(): void {
    this.categoryService.getTrendingCategories()
        .subscribe(categories => {
            this.trendingCategories = categories;
            console.log(categories);
        });
  }

 }
 


please share the code of CategoriesStyleThreeComponent TS file!

Add component code

If CategoriesStyleThreeComponent is standalone, then ensure you have added CommonModule to the imports array!
CommonModule contains the directives like ngClass and ngIf to use in the HTML, you can also import these individual items separately.
Standalone component require the imports to be added on the component, since they can function as a individual unit, without depending on modules!
...
@Component({
  ...
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    ...
    CommonModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class CategoriesStyleThreeComponent {
    ...


Oh thank you so much. you are more updated than ChatGpt 2021 lol:)

In Angular 17, in most cases you should not use *ngIf anymore. You can use @if(condition) directly in your html file without importing any module. As an example:
@if(trendingCategories) {
  <div class="row" [class.dark-category-box]="themeService.isDark()">
}

If you want to use *ngIf, I recommend you just import NgIf and not the CommonModule. The CommonModule was popular in the old version, but it includes a lot of stuff you do not need in your component, which makes it unnecessarily bigger. Below is an example of all the stuff you import into your component when you use the CommonModule.
import { 
  AsyncPipe,
  CurrencyPipe,
  DatePipe,
  DecimalPipe,
  I18nPluralPipe,
  I18nSelectPipe,
  JsonPipe,
  KeyValuePipe,
  LowerCasePipe,
  NgClass,
  NgComponentOutlet,
  NgForOf,
  NgIf,
  NgPlural,
  NgStyle,
  NgSwitch,
  NgTemplateOutlet,
  PercentPipe,
  SlicePipe,
  TitleCasePipe,
  UpperCasePipe } from '@angular/common';

You can read more about the new control-flow from angular here.

+1 for recommending importing NgIf directly, but I don't think it's completely correct to say that you should always prefer @if.

May I ask why you think it's wrong to say we should always use @if? It's the new control flow of angular, which also supports @else directly without using ng-template. So currently I only see advantages to using @if.

I agree that it's better in nearly all cases (including because it's more legible, it doesn't require imports, it supports wrapping multiple elements in the same conditional without a parent node or <ng-container>, and is more fully featured with @else support) but it also has some drawbacks.

Namely, it's incredibly easy to end up with excessive indentation in the template (particularly when combining with other control flow directives like @for or @defer), *ngIf is consistent with the "shape" of other structural directives, and, while I don't want to argue for familiarity, that might be a consideration for some projects too.

For nearly all cases, I agree with you: just use @if. I don't think that means offering, "you should not use *ngIf anymore," as advice, though.

Thanks for sharing with me. I agree with the part excessive indentation can happen in the new control flow. I personally always split my code into a lot of components (maybe sometimes too many) so i don't have this problem but of course for users who prefer not to split the code into more components it can be wild with the new control flow ;). The point why i usually recommend only the new control flow is cuz i'm worried that maybe in 2-3 years the angular team will say we now remove the old control flow which will force users to adapt with the new control flow.

However, I still agree with you, so edit my answer with "in most cases you should not use *ngIf anymore".

You saved my day. I had the problem with ngif in lazy loaded subcomponent within a component. And changing ngif to @if helped.
